# CSS Toggle transition animation

Tags: html, css, animation, toggle, slide

I have 2 CSS toggle buttons I am making. Right now when you click the button has a fade in and out effect. I want to to act more like a sliding from right to left animation. Attached is the HTML, CSS and a l ink to a fiddle with my code. Thank you! https://jsfiddle.net/ebgpqvha/

```
<div class="switch-field">
  <div class="switch-title">Hand:</div>
  <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" checked/>
  <label for="switch_left">L</label>
  <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" />
  <label for="switch_right">R</label>
</div>


       .switch-field, .switch-field2 {
      font-family: "adiHaus", Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin: 0.2em;
        overflow: hidden;
    }       


    .switch-title {
      margin-bottom: 6px;
    }       

    .switch-field input, .switch-field2 input {
      display: none;
    }       


    .switch-field label, .switch-field2 label {
      float: left;
    }       


    .switch-field label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 63px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #EFEFEF;
      color: #cdcdcd;
      font: 16px "adiHaus",Arial,sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: none;
      padding: 10px 14px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     border-top: #CCC solid 1px;
     border-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom: #EEE solid 1px;
        border-right: #ddd solid 1px;
        border-left: #ddd solid 1px;
      -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
      transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    }       

    .switch-field2 label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 113px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #EFEFEF;
      color: #cdcdcd;
      font: 16px "adiHaus",Arial,sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: none;
      padding: 10px 14px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     border-top: #CCC solid 1px;
     border-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom: #EEE solid 1px;
        border-right: #ddd solid 1px;
        border-left: #ddd solid 1px;
     -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
      transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    }       

    .switch-field label:hover, .switch-field2 label:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }       

    .switch-field input:checked + label, .switch-field2 input:checked + label {
      background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      color:000;
      font-weight: bold;
    }       

    .switch-field label:first-of-type, .switch-field2 label:first-of-type {
    border-right: none;
    }       

    .switch-field label:last-of-type, .switch-field2 label:last-of-type {
    border-left: none;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do this with your current html. This is because they easily could be separate and still work - to slide it would have to be one check box. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/CalvT/227dk2ow/ - let me know if thats what you want and I'll post an answer

Comment: Sure, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CalvT is right unless you just want just the slide effect for the bg as an example https://jsfiddle.net/ebgpqvha/1/

Comment: Or like this one https://jsfiddle.net/ebgpqvha/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to use two check boxes for this. Well you probably could, but I personally think it would be far too messy to be any good. So instead, you should include a field in your table, which is titled something like "Right Handed" and the answer is yes or no.

So you create a checkbox like so:

I've enclosed it in a table so that I can add the LH and RH either side.

```css
.tgl {
  display: none;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #3f9ddd;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:after,
.tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  display: none;
}
.tgl:checked + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 50%;
}
.tgl:checked + .tgl-btn {
  background: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Hand</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LH</td>
    <td>
      <input class="tgl" id="cb1" type="checkbox">
      <label class="tgl-btn" for="cb1"></label>
    </td>
    <td>RH</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So the checkbox ends up checked if the person is Right Handed.

This requires no JavaScript, the CSS is based on whether the checkbox is checked or not using the `:checked` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You can try  [MoreToggles.css](https://github.com/JNKKKK/MoreToggles.css) which is a pure CSS library.

You can choose a style which has sliding from right to left animation as you like.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/JNKKKK/MoreToggles.css/output/moretoggles.min.css">
</head>
```

```html
<div class="mt-ios"> 
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="1"></label>
</div>
```